# How to extend config of different bundle in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I know I can overwrite templates or extend classes of other bundles. But can I extend also configs? I was hoping to be able to load other namespaces from config in `DependenyInjection/AcmeExtension.php`'s load method, but I haven't found anything about it anywhere.

**Example:**

I have AcmeBundle which defines following in config:

```
acme:
    a: 1
```

I want to extend this bundle (in new bundle called AwesomeAcmeBundle) and be able to define another variables either by adding them to original namespace:

```
acme:
    a: 1
    b: 2
```

or by wrapping original namespace to new one and adding new variables there:

```
awesome_acme:
    a: 1
    b: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar needs and I have solved them in the following way:

1) Extend the parent's Configuration class

```
//FooBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php

use DerpBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration as BaseConfiguration;

class Configuration extends BaseConfiguration
{

    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = parent::getConfigTreeBuilder();

        //protected attribute access workaround
        $reflectedClass = new \ReflectionObject($treeBuilder);
        $property = $reflectedClass->getProperty("root");
        $property->setAccessible(true);

        $rootNode = $property->getValue($treeBuilder);

        $rootNode
           ->children()
           ...

        return $treeBuilder;
     }
}
```

2) Create own extension that actually can handle the new configuration entries

```
class FooExtension extends Extension
{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        //custom parameters
        $container->setParameter('new_param_container_name', $config['new_param_name']);

     ...
     }
}
```

3) in the `app\config\config.yml` you can use in your new `foo` attribute-set all the parameters that `derp` (as a parent bundle) has plus any of your new params that you have defined in the `Configuration.php`.

Comment: I had to add some extra config to an existing bundle config. Under the root node of that existing bundle. It wouldn't work in this way because symfony doesn't allow for any other root name than the underscored version of your bundle name. Do you know a way to really extend an existing config tree, while staying under the same root node?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the `.yml`s, you can import the `AcmeBundle`s confing in the `AwesomeAcmeBundle` config with

```
imports:
    - { resource: path/to/AcmeBundles/config.yml }
```

and then overwrite the parameters you want.

Symfony is doing the same in the `config_dev.yml` with the `framework/router` parameter.

Comment: No, that's not exactly what I meant. I want to extend configuration (aka `DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`) of some bundle, not just the config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
imports:
 - { resource: @YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
```